# Implement autocapitalisation in Swift

Tags: swift, textbox, capitalization

I searched about autocapitalisation of a word in Swift on internet as well as on this site. I found the solutions but the solution is working for me. can you help me with this?

I have set capitalisation property of through text box property. screenshot is as follows:

[image]

I did the same thing through program also as follows, but nothing works for me:

```
txtabc.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationType.Words;
```

Comment: In what method do you set this property?

Comment: @Kirsteins - func txtabc(sender: UIButton) {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set your keyboard type as Name Phone Pad, which does not support auto-capitalization.

From [UITextInputTraits Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/UITextInputTraits/autocapitalizationType):

> Some keyboard types do not support auto-capitalization. Specifically, this option is ignored if the value in the keyboardType property is set to UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad, UIKeyboardTypePhonePad, or **UIKeyboardTypeNamePhonePad**.

You could try with some other keyboard types and it should work properly.